# Validation: to make sure the string is a number

Tags: java, string, validation, double, try-catch

I'm writing code for my coursework, and I need help on the validation. I want to make sure that the string entered is a number.
 I was given a piece of code from my teacher with try and catch, and it does work but it has a problem which I don't know how to solve.

So if someone could help me out by telling me whats wrong with this code it'd be much appreciated, or if someone could give me another simple code to validate the data to make sure its a number.

```
boolean StartTimeIsANumber; // BOOLEAN CREATED
  StartTimeIsANumber = false; // BOOLEAN SET TO FALSE
  double starttime=0; // VARIBALE IS INITIALISED

  System.out.println("Please enter the start time in seconds"); // asks for time in seconds

  while(StartTimeIsANumber==false) // WHILE OK IS FALSE
   {
    try {

     String input; // start time is stored as a string
     input = kb.next(); // reads the start time in as a string
     starttime = Double.parseDouble(input); // converts to double
     System.out.println("start time: "+starttime); // outputs the start time
     StartTimeIsANumber =true; // if its a number boolean set will convert to true and will break out of the loop
     }  catch (NumberFormatException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      // e.printStackTrace(); (this is the line that makes red writing, commenting it out stops red writing)
      System.out.println("start time must be a number"); // further 'advice'
              }

   }
```

I have a picture of what it does, see below. The number of words I write is the number of times it outputs 'start time must be a number'!

[image]

Comment: Your `catch` block is catching the `Exception` thrown by the `parseDouble` method when trying to parse a `String` which is not a double-valued `String`. This looks fine.

Comment: Have you tried entering number in form `22` instead of `twenty two`?

Comment: Wow, that's a source you got from your teacher? You need to replace your teacher. :-(

Comment: How is `kb` declared and initialized?

Comment: What you call "red writing" is probably a "compile error" - however, I can copy-paste your code into an IDE and that e.printStackTrace() line is fine...

Comment: Indeed, I get this for your input: Please enter the start time in seconds
twentytwo
start time must be a number
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "twentytwo"
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1222)
 at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:510)
 at Tmp.main(Tmp.java:26)

Comment: so what do i have to do to make this work properly?

Comment: @gilleain , this sort of message is inappropriate for the comment format. You can put formatted output or multiple-line code in here.

Comment: what do i need to add/take away from my code? @RealSkeptic

Comment: @rav, it is working properly. Nobody told you that it's supposed to return just one such reply. It checks each word you enter to see if it's a number, because you may enter something like "oops 22.5", so it will succeed in the `22.5`.

Comment: ohhh! okay thankyou!! didnt think of it that way! @RealSkeptic

Answer (score 0):

It iterates on every word of the line. You have to consider the whole input line as one statement.

```
boolean StartTimeIsANumber = false; 
double starttime=0; // VARIBALE IS INITIALISED
String input = "";

System.out.println("Please enter the start time in seconds");

while(StartTimeIsANumber == false) {
    try {
        while (kb.hasNext()) {
            input += (kb.next() + " ");  
        }
        // or input = kb.nextLine();

        starttime = Double.parseDouble(input);
        System.out.println("start time: " + starttime);
        StartTimeIsANumber = true;
    }  catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("start time must be a number");
    }
}
```

Comment: It might be simpler to clear the rest of the line with a `kb.nextLine();` call.

Comment: could you comment the bits that you've added please, as im only 14 and do not know what they do? would help so much if you could! Thanks for the help though! :D @jvDx